# New tag for movie - should be specific or general

Tags: discussion

I asked a new question about specific [escape room](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106156/explanation-for-the-ice-room-solution) movie, and a tag escape room was created

> The escape-room tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

Should I edit escape room tag with specific movie (2019) or genre of escape room movies?

There are at least 2019 and 2017 movies named *Escape Room*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For movie *title* tags the wiki should be about that *specific* movie.

A don't think a meta-tag for "escape rooms" is required here...there aren't going to be *that* many questions on that subject.

---

### Tag names

For movies with the same name we have the current approach....

On first question for a new movie tag - We create the tag with just the name of the movie... so [escape-room](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/escape-room).

On first question for a movie with same name but **different year** - We create *new* tag with the year appended... e.g. [escape-room-2017](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/escape-room-2017)

Comment: I was halfway through writing an answer of my own, but this pretty much covers everything. One minor thing: IMDb actually lists [two](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5159414/) [movies](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5748392/) called *Escape Room* that were released in 2017. What would happen if we received separate questions about both? Is there a precedent?

Comment: Side note there will be a sequel in 2020 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_Room_(film)

Comment: @F1Krazy - No I don't there is a precedent for that. I'd not be worrying until someone has a question. In order words, we'll deal with it when it happens ☺